# How to remove 404 errors of the web service from the console?

Tags: forms, error-handling, xhtml, http-status-code-404, orbeon

How can I remove the **404 error** from the Web service from the console?

I managed to remove the 404 from the web service by adding a condition (if the web service parameter is not null).
But I could not do it if the field belongs to a repeatable section(if I put a condition of its parameter, the web service does not work in the other iterations).

Also during the saving of the forms, I noticed that there are several 404 errors in the Web service.
This is a stacktrace when the errors was occured:

```
> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"}
2017-12-13 11:37:30,835 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|xf:submission for submission id: getStatutGestion-submission, error code received when submitting instance: 404       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsSubmissionException                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|getReplacer                   |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 722|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        | 108|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  78|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission    |submitCallable                |BaseSubmission.scala          |  89|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission |connect                       |RegularSubmission.java        | 131|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|doSubmit                      |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 453|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|performDefaultAction          |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 283|
|ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                | 130|
|ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  79|
|ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  79|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Logging$class                  |withDebug                     |Logging.scala                 |  50|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withDebug                     |Dispatch.scala                |  28|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                |  79|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  78|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  78|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withEvent$1                   |Dispatch.scala                |  43|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |dispatchEvent                 |Dispatch.scala                |  77|
|g.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.actions.XFormsSendAction|execute                       |XFormsSendAction.scala        |  51|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAction          |execute                       |XFormsAction.scala            |  34|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterpreter|runSingleIteration            |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 221|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterpreter|runAction                     |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 157|
|ction.actions.XFormsActionAction$$anonfun$execute$2|apply                         |XFormsActionAction.scala      |  79|
|ction.actions.XFormsActionAction$$anonfun$execute$2|apply                         |XFormsActionAction.scala      |  67|
|scala.collection.Iterator$class                    |foreach                       |Iterator.scala                | 893|
|scala.collection.AbstractIterator                  |foreach                       |Iterator.scala                |1336|
|scala.collection.IterableLike$class                |foreach                       |IterableLike.scala            |  72|
|scala.collection.AbstractIterable                  |foreach                       |Iterable.scala                |  54|
|orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.actions.XFormsActionAction|execute                       |XFormsActionAction.scala      |  67|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterpreter|runSingleIteration            |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 221|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterpreter|runAction                     |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 157|
|forms.event.EventHandlerImpl$$anonfun$handleEvent$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |EventHandlerImpl.scala        | 256|
|forms.event.EventHandlerImpl$$anonfun$handleEvent$1|apply                         |EventHandlerImpl.scala        | 256|
|forms.event.EventHandlerImpl$$anonfun$handleEvent$1|apply                         |EventHandlerImpl.scala        | 256|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.DynamicVariable                |withValue                     |DynamicVariable.scala         |  42|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAPI$            |withScalaAction               |XFormsAPI.scala               |  47|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.EventHandlerImpl       |handleEvent                   |EventHandlerImpl.scala        | 255|
|$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                |  98|
|$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  97|
|$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  97|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Logging$class                  |withDebug                     |Logging.scala                 |  50|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 305|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 210|
|org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter        |doFilter                      |WsFilter.java                 |  51|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 243|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 210|
|org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter             |handleSimpleCORS              |CorsFilter.java               | 302|
|org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter             |doFilter                      |CorsFilter.java               | 170|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 243|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 210|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.FormRunnerAuthFilter        |doFilter                      |FormRunnerAuthFilter.scala    |  26|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 243|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 210|
|doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |LimiterFilter.scala           |  85|
|doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  85|
|doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  85|
|org.orbeon.oxf.logging.LifecycleLogger$            |withEvent                     |LifecycleLogger.scala         | 124|
|.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |LimiterFilter.scala           |  84|
|.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  78|
|.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  78|
|org.orbeon.oxf.logging.LifecycleLogger$            |withEvent                     |LifecycleLogger.scala         | 124|
|rbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  78|
|rbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  72|
|scala.Option                                       |foreach                       |Option.scala                  | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter               |doFilter                      |LimiterFilter.scala           |  72|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 243|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 210|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve      |invoke                        |StandardWrapperValve.java     | 222|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve      |invoke                        |StandardContextValve.java     | 123|
|org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase|invoke                        |AuthenticatorBase.java        | 502|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke                        |StandardHostValve.java        | 171|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve        |invoke                        |ErrorReportValve.java         | 100|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve          |invoke                        |AccessLogValve.java           | 953|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve       |invoke                        |StandardEngineValve.java      | 118|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service                       |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 408|
|org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor   |process                       |AbstractHttp11Processor.java  |1041|
|e.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler|process                       |AbstractProtocol.java         | 603|
|.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor|run                           |JIoEndpoint.java              | 312|
|java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor            |runWorker                     |ThreadPoolExecutor.java       |1142|
|java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker     |run                           |ThreadPoolExecutor.java       | 617|
|java.lang.Thread                                   |run                           |Thread.java                   | 745|
```

Comment: You're calling a service you provided, right? Why is that service returning a 404? I imagine that it shouldn't, right? Or are you saying that you're OK that your service returns a 404, and would just like the error not to show in the console?

Comment: when opening a form, Orbeon will call the services of this form and there are services with parameters they are empty when opening, which is why they display error 404, but I want to make conditions to these services only work if the parameters are met, this loading of the services which makes exceptions in the console will make the loading of the form opening more cumbersome.

Comment: for repeatable sections how can i make conditions on a field that belongs to this section because i put the name of the field but the service only works in the first iteration. Also when registering the form, orbeon will call the service and return 404.

Comment: Rather than not *showing* the error, it would be better for the error not to happen. So I gather that sometimes your form is loaded with parameters, sometimes without, and the service returns a 404 if the parameters are not present. Would it work for you if the service wasn't called on form load if the parameters are not present?

Comment: Lebki, just checking:did you get to solve this issue, or maybe this isn't a priority anymore?

Comment: I have not yet solved the problem, I have web service with parameters that are filled in the creation of the form, but when opening this form all web service will be called but the parameters are empty that's why it makes 404 error, in services in orbeon we can make conditions for the call of the web service, but in the repeteable section we can not make a condition if this field is empty, because the service works that in the first iteration but in the other iteration the service no longer works.

Comment: how can i do this for the repeteable section and why when saving the form it displays in the log 404 error for webservice (not all web serivces) and how it can be solved.
thank you

Comment: Lebki, could you create a minimal form that shows the issue, and that calls a publicly available service so I can run from my end, so I can get a better idea of what you're talking about, and maybe modify that example to prototype what you're looking for? (You can post the source of that form as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), and link to it in a comment.)